# Put together two selects in one table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two queries which I would like to combine into one table in SQL Server.

First query:

```
declare @NAME varchar(40), @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime

set @NAME='Nancy'
set @startDate='2014-04-2'
set @endDate='2014-04-28'

SELECT 
   USERINFO.USERID, USERINFO.NAME, USERINFO.TITLE, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, 
   CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE, CHECKINOUT.trans 
FROM 
   att..USERINFO 
INNER JOIN 
   att..CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID 
WHERE 
   (USERINFO.NAME = @NAME) 
   AND (@NAME <> '-1') 
   AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate + ' 23:59:00.000') 
   OR (@NAME = '-1') 
   AND (CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate + ' 23:59:00.000') 
   AND (1 = 1)
```

Results:

```
USERID  NAME    TITLE       CHECKTIME              CHECKTYPE    trans
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 07:58:36.000    I          29
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 12:00:27.000    O          30
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 13:00:02.000    I          31
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 16:57:45.000    O          32
```

Second query:

```
SELECT  
   USERID
   , convert(varchar(10),CHECKTIME,101) as Date
   , SUM(CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = 'I' 
                 THEN -1 * (datepart(hh, [CHECKTIME]) + datepart(mi, [CHECKTIME]) / 60.0)
                 ELSE datepart(hh, [CHECKTIME]) + datepart(mi, [CHECKTIME]) / 60.0   
         END) AS Hours
   , MAX(trans) as transs
INTO #temp
FROM att..[CHECKINOUT]
WHERE USERID = 1003
GROUP BY 
    USERID, CONVERT(varchar(10), [CHECKTIME], 101)

SELECT 
   USERID, Date, LEFT(Hours,2) as Hr, (RIGHT(Hours,6)*60) as Min, transs
INTO #temp2
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT 
   USERID, Convert(nvarchar(50), Hr) + Convert(nvarchar(50), Min) as HWORKED, 
   Date, transs
FROM #temp2

DROP TABLE #temp2
```

Results

```
USERID  HWORKED     Date        transs
-----------------------------------------
1003    7.59000040  04/28/2014  32
1003    7.54000060  04/29/2014  36
1003    4957999960  04/30/2014  40
1003    4957999960  05/01/2014  44
```

My desired result is to be able to put the two queries together and get this result(using the trans as the join:

```
USERID  NAME    TITLE       CHECKTIME              CHECKTYPE    trans tranns HWORKED
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 07:58:36.000    I          29    NULL  0
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 12:00:27.000    O          30    NULL  0
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 13:00:02.000    I          31    NULL  0
1003    Nancy   Manufactura 2014-04-28 16:57:45.000    O          32    32    7.59000040
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just joining them?  The easiest way to express it is probably with ctes:

```
with t1 as (
      <first query here>
     ),
     t2 as (
      <second query here>
     )
select t1.*, t2.HWORKED, t2.Date
from t1 left outer join
     t2
     on t1.trans = t2.transs and t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

Comment: This seems to be much better than physically joining them. Maybe with some indexes.

Comment: The second query inside the t2 as() is giving me problems it says incorrect syntax near 'INTO' #temp. any ideas?

Comment: I was told yoou can put a query that inserts to temp table in a WITH clause.

Comment: Im stuck, I need to figure this out. pleas help thanks

Comment: @JohnVega . . . You need to remove the `into` clause and any `order by` clauses in the common table expression (the "with" queries).

Comment: but iFs I remove the into I wont be able to insert into temp table and I need the temp table

Comment: @JohnVega . . . Just use a series of CTEs instead of temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't know CTEs existed. I just learned it with your help. thanks!